# Why would a call to WSASocket() vs socket() cause sends to block?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have two simple wrapper classes for TCPConnection and TCPListener. The application that uses these classes is running on Windows 10 and does the following:

- Thread 1

  - Calls getaddrinfo, socket, bind, listen, accept and blocks waiting for a connection
  - When a connection is established, the client socket is passed to a second thread for sending
  - Starts blocking recv() loop
- Thread 2

  - Waits for queued sending data
  - Calls send() when data is available in queue

This works perfectly when I create the server socket using the socket() call. When I switch to the WSASocket() call (non overlapped), the send calls whether send() or WSASend() will block if there is a pending recv() or WSARecv() call that is blocking.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this. Its always been my understanding that sends and recvs on the same socket from different threads was ok.

**Are there differences in the implementation under the hood between the posix vs WSA variants? Any idea what could cause this behavior?**

Call difference is as follows:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPOROTO_TCP);
sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPOROTO_TCP, nullptr, 0, 0);
```

The connecting client is from Python 3.8.5

Comment: The only thing I can think of is somehow the TCP stack is different, and python endpoint is reporting the window being empty, so the send blocks. But haven't verified and that seems highly unlikely...

Comment: Wireshark appears to show that the data is not being sent, which indicates the send is in fact blocked waiting on some kind of kernel object. The window appears to be large enough.

Answer (score 4):

When using *WSASocket()* you need to pass the *WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED* flag in order to get the same behavior as calls to socket(). Without it windows will block your *WSASend()* or *send()* calls if a *WSARecv()* or *recv()* is blocked in another thread.

I was under the assumption that if I passed the *WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED* flag all my socket operations would be overlapped (i.e. all calls to *WSARecv()* and *WSASend()* would require an *OVERLAPPED* structure), but that is not the case.

Correct usage:

```
sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPOROTO_TCP, nullptr, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
WSABUF buf { bufferLen, bufferPtr};
DWORD bytes = 0;
DWORD flags = 0;
WSARecv(sock, &buf, 1, &bytes, &flags, nullptr, nullptr); // Thread 1
WSASend(sock, &buf, 1, &bytes, 0, nullptr, nullptr);      //Thread 2
```

Is the same as doing:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPOROTO_TCP);
recv(sock, bufferPtr, bufferLen, 0); // Thread 1
send(sock, bufferPtr, bufferLen); // Thread 2
```

On Windows, you just don't have access to the OVERLAPPED features.

Comment: Jamie, the current MSDN documentation for the socket() call states that "The socket that is created will have the overlapped attribute as a default." so it's expected that to create a functionally equivalent socket with WSASocket you would need the WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag. However, I agree that it's a bit strange and unexpected that WSASend() blocks on a WSARecv call if WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED is NOT set. I hadn't realised that was the case, so I've learnt something new this morning, thank you.